# Load EE Field Type in Third Party Module

Tags: wygwam, module, fieldtype

I am trying to load wygwam field type into a custom module, on my localhost the following works:

```
require_once(APPPATH . 'fieldtypes/EE_FieldType.php');
require_once(PATH_THIRD.'wygwam/ft.wygwam.php');
$wyg = new Wygwam_ft();
```

however when i upload to my server i get the following error:

```
require_once(../system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/EE_fieldType.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I dont know why thats happening. Is there a better way to load the wygwam Field type? or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking carefully at your error message, you may have some incorrect capitalization of the EE_Fieldtype class file name. `EE_Fieldtype.php` is the correct way (uppercase F, lowercase t). Likely your localhost is case insensitive but your server is not.

Comment: yep, that was it. when i first fixed the case i put 'EE_FieldType' so my own fault. thanks for the clarification on the case sensitivity - didnt know about that.